# Angular 2 Cascading Select - Reset dependent list on change

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am building a cascading select directive. Which when applied on a select list, monitors changes in its value and if there is any update, it emits the updated list which the dependent component uses to populate dropdown.

I want to set the value of the dependent dropdown list to null whenever the select list with this directive is changed.

Example:

```
<select cascade ngControl="country" (change)="form.controls.state.updateValue(null)" (data)="statesList=$event;">
<option>Country 1</option>
<option>Country 2</option>
</select>


<select ngControl="state">
<option *ngFor="let state of statesList" [value]="state.id">{{state.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Currently I am using

```
(change)="form.controls.state.updateValue(null)"
```

to reset, I am wondering is there any better way to set form.controls.state to null.

May be any way through which I could pass a the dependent control to the cascade directive which reset its value to null.

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.